# Can't see Process Management in KIE workbench menu

Tags: drools, jbpm, kie, kie-workbench, drools-kie-workbench

I am running KIE Drools workbench version 7.5.0 (`kie-drools-wb-7.5.0.Final-wildfly10.war`) on WildFly 10. On my workbench, I can create a new project and add a new Business Process. However, I can't access the Process Management page that most tutorials show because the menu doesn't display it at all. See the screenshot to get a clearer idea of what I am saying.

[image]

My KIE Workbench shows Projects and Dashboard under Design, Deployments and Execution Servers under DevOps and Business Dashboards under Track. Most tutorials show that this menu has much more than this, atleast a Process Management option.

So the problem is I can't see the Process Management option in my menu. Can somebody help me out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kie Workbench has a few variations, the one you're trying (kie-drools-wb) is target for authoring and deploying rules only. To have access the full set process related features, please try kie-wb instead: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/kie/kie-wb/7.5.0.Final/kie-wb-7.5.0.Final-wildfly10.war